# Running totals for a windowed query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE gps_history (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id integer,
  date_time timestamp without time zone,
  speed integer,
  lat double precision,
  lng double precision );
```

sample data inserts available on [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/qfJUUWxd)

I need a query by date range, and device_id, that will return total distance, total time spent moving, total time spent stopped, total number of stops, and total idle time (idle is the same as stopped but when stopped for more that 5 minutes idle time is accrued rather than stop time). All of this by day even if the range is say 2 weeks.

One noted quirk, if there is a gap between any 2 records of 5 minutes or more, that means the device was powered off and the time during that gap should be ignored.

What I have so far is a windowed query so I can look back to determine stopped / moving state and which to accrue the time for. The main problem I am having is being able to say the idle time because the time in prior records has already been added to stopped time and not idle.

```
SELECT device_id,
         to_char(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as period,
         sum(distance) AS total_distance,
         sum(time_diff) as total_time,
         sum(stop_time) as stop_time,
         sum(move_time) as move_time,
         sum(is_new_stop) as total_stops
FROM (
   SELECT device_id,
          date_time,
          lat,
          lng,
          speed,

          CASE
            WHEN lag(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) IS NULL --is first row
                THEN 0
            ELSE
                ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat),4326), lag(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat) ,4326), 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time))
          END AS distance,

        CASE
            WHEN lag(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) IS NULL --is first row
                THEN 0
            WHEN  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) )) > 300 --longer than 5 mins so 0
                THEN 0
            WHEN speed > 0 and (lag(speed, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time)) > 0
                THEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) ))
            ELSE 0
        END AS move_time, -- last rec and this one moving, so accrue move time

        CASE
            WHEN lag(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) IS NULL --is first row
                THEN 0
            WHEN  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) )) > 300 --longer than 5 mins so 0
                THEN 0
            WHEN speed = 0 and (lag(speed, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time)) = 0
                THEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) ))
            ELSE 0
        END AS stop_time, -- last rec and this one 0 speed, so accrue stop time

        CASE
            WHEN lag(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) IS NULL --is first row
                THEN 0
            WHEN  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) )) > 300 --longer than 5 mins so 0
                            THEN 0
            ELSE
                EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) ))
        END AS time_diff, -- time diff since last record

         CASE
            WHEN lag(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) IS NULL and speed = 0--is first row
                THEN 1
            WHEN  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( date_time - lag(date_time, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) )) > 300 and speed = 0
                THEN 1
            WHEN lag(speed, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) > 0 and speed = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE
                0
        END AS is_new_stop -- time diff since last record


   FROM   gps_history
   WHERE device_id = 5000 and date_time >= '2015-12-7' and date_time < '2015-12-8'
   ORDER BY date_time
   ) sub
GROUP BY device_id, to_char(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Note : `to_char(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD');` is not needed in the order by. `ORDER BY date_time` will do exactly the same. (similar for GROUP BY, but you'll need `datepart()` there )

Comment: I'm all about getting it done in SQL when possible, and this certainly seems possible.  That said, I think a scripting language would make really short order of this task.  Is this something you're open to, or do you really need a purely DB solution?

Comment: @Hambone in a lot of cases there are several hundred thousand records and between network latency and other factors I'm just trying to optimize as much as possible. It is done in code now and even using cursors it still isn't quite cutting it.

Comment: you should post a small amount of data of worst case scenario to work with. Its quite hard to grasp whats data actually like.

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy updated with a pastebin link to inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spent a couple of hours on this and came up with this gibberish query:

```
with
   main as (select *  FROM   gps_history WHERE device_id = 5000 and date_time >= '2015-08-10' and date_time < '2015-10-30' ORDER BY date_time)
  ,main_1 as(select *, lag(date_time) over(partition by device_id order by device_id, date_time) l_date_time, lag(speed) over(partition by device_id order by device_id, date_time) l_speed 
                 , coalesce( ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat),4326), lag(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat) ,4326), 1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) ),0) :: numeric(30,4) as distance
from main)
,main_2 as (select *, case WHEN  EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM (date_time -l_date_time) ) > 300  THEN -1
        when EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM (date_time -l_date_time)) < 300 and speed = 0 then 0
        when EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM (date_time -l_date_time)) < 300 and speed > 0 then 1
        else -1
        end::integer as state ,           
        coalesce(  EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM (date_time -l_date_time)), 0) time_elapsed
from main_1)

,main_3 as( select device_id, date_time,speed,state,distance,time_elapsed  ,sum(distance ) over (order by date_time ) ::numeric(30,4) travelled , case when state in (-1,0) and lag( state) over(order by date_time) =1 then 1 else 0 end stops    from main_2)
,main_4 as( select device_id , max(date_time) date_time , speed  , state , sum(distance) distance ,  sum(time_elapsed) time_elapsed,  travelled , sum(stops) as stops from main_3 group by device_id  ,state  ,speed ,travelled order by date_time)

 select 
  sum( case when state in (-1) then  time_elapsed else 0 end) offline_time
 ,sum( case when state in (0,1) then  time_elapsed else 0 end) total_time
 ,sum( case when state in (1) then  time_elapsed else 0 end) move_time
 ,sum( case when state in (0) and time_elapsed <=300 then  time_elapsed else 0 end) stop_time
 ,sum( case when state in (0) and time_elapsed > 300 then  time_elapsed else 0 end) idle_time
 ,sum( stops) stops
 ,sum(distance) distance 
 from main_4
```

you will need to alter it a bit to suit your need, based on your data discovered a dilemma. because gps readings fluctuated when the car was stationary, had to round it to make some query logic working and discovered that there was no time frame where car actually was stationary more than 5 min, based on gps position readings, seemed that car was cought in some traffic jam and slowly moved and gps  didn't pick up the speed.  so , playing with rounding travelled distance to 4 decimal digits (per gps reading intervals) to interpret that traffic jam time as idle time. ...

hope this helps